# Facebook Graph API PHP SDK not recognizing session variable

Tags: php, facebook, session, facebook-graph-api

I am developing an application where I am getting messages from conversations. Here is my code:

```
// facebook SDK startup
$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
  'app_id' => '[my_app_id]',
  'app_secret' => '[my_app_secret]',
  'default_graph_version' => 'v2.4',
]);


$request = new Facebook\FacebookRequest(
                          $session,
                        'GET',
                        '/{converation-id}',
                        array(
                            'fields' => 'gender'
                                )
                            );

                            $response = $request->execute();
                            $graphObject = $response->getGraphObject();
                            /* handle the result */
                          var_dump($graphObject);
```

When I run this, i get this error:

> Undefined variable: $session

I know that I haven't initialized it but I am confused that what value do I have to assign to it or where do I need to connect this variable? Any suggestions?

Comment: That seems to be outdated code, written for the PHP SDK v4. In the current version v5, this takes different parameters: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/FacebookRequest/5.0.0

Answer (score 0):

This one is outdated.

For the newest versions you don't need the `$session` variable. In the newer versions the `$request->execute()` method is missing, too.

Try something like this:

```
// facebook SDK startup
$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
  'app_id' => '[my_app_id]',
  'app_secret' => '[my_app_secret]',
  'default_graph_version' => 'v2.4',
]);

$request = $fb->request('GET', '/{conversation-id}', array('fields' => 'gender'));

// Send the request to Graph
try {
  $response = $fb->getClient()->sendRequest($request);
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
  // When Graph returns an error
  echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
  // When validation fails or other local issues
  echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
}

$graphNode = $response->getGraphNode();
var_dump($graphNode);
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem from FB SDK.
I have tried the code from Fabian, and it requests me to add the access token now.

```
$request = $fb->request(
  'GET',
  '/{conversation-id}',
  array(
    'fields' => 'posts.limit(10)',
    'access_token' => '{token_id}'
  )
);
```

And it works! I got the array result.